# Email alerts based on Multi-select picklist values

Tags: workflow, multi-select

The campaign has a multiselect picklist for Sales Theater (Values = AMER, APAC, PBST, Global etc) and wants to send an email alert to corresponding Distro List.
Examples below:
1. Selected picklist value is APAC, only send email to APAC distro list. 
2. Selected picklist values = AMER, APAC, PBST, then the email alert should be sent out to all 3 DL's.

How can I achieve this without creating one workflow for each picklist value? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of ease of use, you could use one process builder with a criteria for each scenario. All your criteria in one location:

1. If picklist contains "APAC" --> email alert to APAC
2. If picklist contains "AMER" --> email alert to AMER
   etc.

No matter what, you're going to have to have different email alerts for each specific distribution if using workflow/process builder. It also gives you the ability to potentially have language specific templates for each distro too if that's important. No way around separate email alerts unless you want to code something (or maybe use flow) and create a custom metadata type for a mapping of picklist to distros to dynamically populate the to address.

Comment: Thank you for the solution Kris. I considered the custom metadata type for a mapping of picklist to distros to dynamically populate the to address, but in that case I will need to create that many email fields. Hence, was looking for another option. Will check the process builder option.

Comment: In terms of code, if it's all the same email template - you can just split the multipicklist, pull all distros associated to the values in one query (WHERE Label in: multipicklistValuesinListForm) and then put all the emails in the list of metadata records into the same To Address.